# Second todo edit click will render textarea on the First todo

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql

On Chrome, Clicking on First todo's edit button and closing it by clicking on close button, then after clicking on edit button of Second todo will render textarea on First todo as well rather keeping it and also after edit button is clicked, close click will not work on Firefox, can someone please suggest what is wrong and what could be done ? Thanks!

```
    class Form extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            text: "",
            val: [],
            close: [],
            closeObj: {id: '', isEdit: false},
            idChk: 0
        }

      }


      handleEditClick = (e,id,text) => {
        let { val, close, closeObj, idChk } = this.state;
        val.push(id);
        this.setState({val});
        closeObj = Object.assign({}, closeObj);
        let chkId = close.findIndex(obj => {
          if(obj.id === id) {
            return id
          }
        })
        if(chkId === -1) {
          closeObj.id = id;
          closeObj.isEdit = !closeObj.isEdit;
          this.setState({closeObj});
          close.push(closeObj);
        }else {
          close[chkId].isEdit = !close[chkId].isEdit;
          this.setState({closeObj, close});
        }
        this.setState({closeObj: {id: '', isEdit: false}, idChk: id});
      }



     handleCloseClick = id => {
       let { close } = this.state;
        for(var i in close) {
          if(close[i].id === id) {
            close[i].isEdit = !close[i].isEdit;
            this.setState({close, idChk: id});
          }
        }
       }


     renderEdit(text, id) {
       return (
         <div>
         <TextField
             onChange={this.handleChange}
             onKeyDown={this.handleKeyDown}
             label=""
             margin="normal"
             value={text}
             color="secondary"
         />
         <Button variant="contained" size="small" style={{color: 'green'}}>
          <SaveIcon />
         </Button>
         <IconButton>
           <CloseIcon onClick={() => this.handleCloseClick(id)}/>
         </IconButton>
         </div>
       )
     }



      render() {
        const { text, idChk, close } = this.state;
        let closeBool = false;
        if( close.length !== 0 ) {
          for (var i in close ) {
            if(idChk === close[i].id) {
              closeBool = close[i].isEdit;
            }
          }
        }


        return (
         <div style={{display: "flex"}}>
          <div style={{margin: "auto", width: 400 }}>
          <TextField
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              onKeyDown={this.handleKeyDown}
              label=""
              margin="normal"
              fullWidth
              value={text}
              color="secondary"
          />
           <Paper elevation={1}>
           <div>
             {this.props.todos.map(todo => (
               <div key={todo.id}>
               {
                 ( this.state.val.includes(todo.id) && closeBool) ? this.renderEdit(todo.text, todo.id):
                 <EditButton todo={todo} val={val} text={text} close={this.state.close}
                             removeTodo={(todo) => this.removeTodo(todo)}
                             handleEditClick={(e, id, text) => this.handleEditClick(e, id, text)}

                             updateTodo={(todo) => this.updateTodo(todo)}
                 />
               }
              </div>
             ))}
           </div>
           </Paper>
         </div>
         </div>
        )
      }
    }
```

Comment: Since you didn't share your `render()` function we don't really see the expected behaviour. Or at least I don't understand it :)

Comment: render function is already present in the question. You don't see it ?

Comment: ahh sorry, scroll not worked, I will check it :)